# How to use x != null in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

DataFrame df01 is as following:

```
scala> df01.show
+--------------------+----+-----+
|          session_id|  材质|count|
+--------------------+----+-----+
|       360098626|120|  金属|    2|
|866693025201992-0...|  布艺|    2|
|        648401717|33|  其它|    1|
|b2df486d906403886...| ABS|    1|
|14962864822301789...|  金属|    2|
|        960455526|12|  金属|    1|
|14886198008411946...| PVC|    1|
|860410037295987-6...|  金属|    1|
|c267e7e20c6742e6d...| ABS|    1|
|862788039750580-1...| ABS|    2|
|85995192767403132...| ABS|    1|
|862681034959357-2...| ABS|    1|
|52f4754fe212caf9d...|  其它|    1|
| 51289594708875916|6|null|    1|
|        741995028|24|null|    1|
|        2099986503|5|  金属|    1|
|14965600686729437...|null|    1|
|15098023912712771...| ABS|    2|
|a28fe88a99e3983c6...|  金属|    2|
|         703270023|2|null|    1|
+--------------------+----+-----+
only showing top 20 rows

scala> df01.schema
res58: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(session_id,StringType,true), StructField(材质,StringType,true), StructField(count,LongType,false))
```

What I want to do is  when the column 材质==null the count is 1. The code is as following:

```
val e = "材质"
```

**type 1:  attr!=null**

```
 val df02 = df01.map{x=>
        val session_id = x(0).toString()
        val attr = x(1).toString()
        var cnt = 1
        if(attr!=null){cnt = x(2).toString().toInt}        
        (session_id,attr,cnt)
       }.toDF("session_id",e,"cnt")
```

**type 2:  attr!="null"**

```
val df02 = df01.map{x=>
    val session_id = x(0).toString()
    val attr = x(1).toString()
    var cnt = 1
    if(attr!="null"){cnt = x(2).toString().toInt}        
    (session_id,attr,cnt)
   }.toDF("session_id",e,"cnt")
```

**type 3:  x(1)!=null**

```
val df02 = df01.map{x=>
    val session_id = x(0).toString()
    val attr = x(1).toString()
    var cnt = 1
    if(x(1)!=null){cnt = x(2).toString().toInt}        
    (session_id,attr,cnt)
   }.toDF("session_id",e,"cnt")
```

**type 4:  x(1)!="null"**

```
val df02 = df01.map{x=>
    val session_id = x(0).toString()
    val attr = x(1).toString()
    var cnt = 1
    if(x(1)!="null"){cnt = x(2).toString().toInt}        
    (session_id,attr,cnt)
   }.toDF("session_id",e,"cnt")
```

All types above is error "*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException*". How to make it right?

Comment: *when the column 材质==null the count is 1*, what does this mean? Do you want to filter the data frame or modify the data frame? For column there is `isNULL` method.

Comment: Modify the data frame.

Comment: The column 材质 is string type, does isNull method work?

Comment: `isNull` works on any data type as long as the values are really nulls.

Comment: For your case I think `when.otherwise` is what you need. `df01.withColumn("count", when(col(e).isNull, 1).otherwise(col("count")))`

Comment: There is na in the column 材质 which must be fill; then the problem will bo solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the @**Psidom** comment is right:

```
df01.withColumn("count", when(col(e).isNull, 1).otherwise(col("count")))
```

Answer (score 0):

When the "材质" column has null value, there will be NullPointException in x(1).toString.

I think the answer in the @Psidom comment is right.